# Pointing to a new database server

Tags: installation, configuration

Our QA team cloned the VM we are using to test our sharepoint mods.

Their cloned version now needs to point to the database on the new box (rather than the developer test sharepoint db).  I disconnected from the farm using the Sharepoint configuration wizard and created a new server farm pointing to the correct database.  To do this we had to delete the sharepoint_config db as well as the Central admin website.  Once we did these two items we were able to get through the configuration wizard successfully.

Now we can't seem to get the Sharepoint Services setup properly.  In the central admin there is no longer a link to manage services on the server.  does anyone have any idea what I should do next to recover the services properly?

Many thanks!

Comment: OK, so a reboot fixed the services issue.  Now I've discovered the website does not appear to be set up properly. There is no file in the following directory C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80 .  Now I suppose I need a wizard to recreate the website :(.  Anyone have any ideas here?

Comment: I ran the configuration wizard in the central administration site and it recreated the website.  It appears all is well now. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative would have been to use a SQL alias on the SharePoint servers, since I assume the database was cloned as well. This would have just pointed the servers to the new SQL servers without them ever knowing it was a different database server.

Comment: Lori, your assumption that the database was cloned as well is correct.  Interesting, thanks for the tip!